# Android Game crashed at facebook login in Kitkat only

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, android-4.4-kitkat

I have integrated facebook unity sdk v5.1.0 in my game I am also using Google playservices for leaderboard.

My game works great on all phone except on kit kat, Moto E, nexus 4, nexus 5. The strange thing is that sometimes it run. but most of the time it crashes

The catch is that I have released the same build with no issues and it was working fine even on kitkat.

But recently my eclipse crashed and I downloaded ADT bundle, it has on androidW SDK and L privew.

I know that something went wrong during the build phase.

So i uninstalled all the sdk and installled only 4.4.2(API level 19)

I am using Unity Ver 4.5.2f1

I have only 4.4.2 (API level 19) in my sdk manager

logs are

```
07-28 18:54:35.664: E/AndroidRuntime(14925): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-28 18:54:35.664: E/AndroidRuntime(14925): Process: com.itecno.cowboysvszombies, PID: 14925
07-28 18:54:35.664: E/AndroidRuntime(14925): java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main]
07-28 18:54:35.664: E/AndroidRuntime(14925): Unity version     : 4.5.2f1
07-28 18:54:35.664: E/AndroidRuntime(14925): Device model      : motorola XT1022
07-28 18:54:35.664: E/AndroidRuntime(14925): Device fingerprint: motorola/condor_retaildsds/condor_umtsds:4.4.4/KXC21.5-40/46:user/release-keys
07-28 18:54:35.664: E/AndroidRuntime(14925): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.itecno.cowboysvszombies/com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-28 18:54:35.664: E/AndroidRuntime(14925):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
07-28 18:54:35.664: E/AndroidRuntime(14925):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
07-28 18:54:35.664: E/AndroidRuntime(14925):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
07-28 18:54:35.664: E/AndroidRuntime(14925):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
07-28 18:54:35.664: E/AndroidRuntime(14925):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-28 18:54:35.664: E/AndroidRuntime(14925):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-28 18:54:35.664: E/AndroidRuntime(14925):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
07-28 18:54:35.664: E/AndroidRuntime(14925):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-28 18:54:35.664: E/AndroidRuntime(14925):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-28 18:54:35.664: E/AndroidRuntime(14925):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-28 18:54:35.664: E/AndroidRuntime(14925):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-28 18:54:35.664: E/AndroidRuntime(14925):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-28 18:54:35.664: E/AndroidRuntime(14925): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-28 18:54:35.664: E/AndroidRuntime(14925):    at com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity.onCreate(FBUnityLoginActivity.java:17)
07-28 18:54:35.664: E/AndroidRuntime(14925):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
07-28 18:54:35.664: E/AndroidRuntime(14925):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
07-28 18:54:35.664: E/AndroidRuntime(14925):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
```

Great help if someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the issue was that i was switching from one scene to another before the call was complete.

And also there are also some clashes with sdk that I am using for ads and analytics
 I m using 5 sdk so there were some clashes ....

sorry for bothering u guys and Facebook support too...where I have filed a bug in the SDK...he he